# Calling function from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a function from this:

```
var _coll = [new Obj('a', somefunction)];

function Obj(id, fn) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fn = fn;
}
var somefunction = (function () {
    return {
        innerFn: function (a) {
            return a
        }
    }
})();
//this works
var test = new Obj('a', somefunction);
alert(test.fn.innerFn('test'));
//this is not working
loopArray();

function loopArray()
for (var it in _coll) {
    for (var its in _coll[it]) {
        var response = _coll[it].fn.innerFn('hey');
        alert(response);
    }
}
}
```

If I change _coll to "var test=new Obj('a','somefunction');", its ok, but how do I call a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because at the point where you define `_coll`, the function `somefunction` is not yet defined.

If you move the call which defines `somefunction` to top of the code, it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

First off you're using a `for..in` loop to access an array, which you should never do, but aside from that...

Within the first loop, `_coll` is the array so `_coll[it]` would be an element of that array. That element is your `Obj` object. Your second `for..in` loop is completely unnecessary and wrong. Surely you can see that you're doing something wrong, since you define a `its` variable that's never used...

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what Kolink said about the loop,
you need to move the line

```
var _coll = [new Obj('a', somefunction)];
```

behind the declaration of somefunction like you did with the line

```
var test = new Obj('a', somefunction);
```

or somefunction will be undefined.